# What is meant by "evenly divisible"?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, terminology

"What is the smallest positive number that is evenly divisible by all of the numbers from 1 to 20?"
Is it different from divisible?

Comment: It is a school version of "divisible."  Used to be fairly common.

Comment: $\rm m\ $ evenly divides $\rm\ n\ $ means simply that $\rm\ n/m\ $ is an integer. The "evenly" presumably means that the remainder upon division is $\:0\:.\:$

Comment: Subareas of mathematics have their own conventions. Is $-5$ a divisor of $20$? Probably one would be expected to answer yes.  What is the sum of the divisors of $20$? Probably one would not be expected to say $0$. It sort of makes sense to qualify divisible, when one means that the quotient is an integer.  After all, $5/20=0.25$.  But the fact is that in mathematics beyond school mathematics, "evenly divisible" is uncommon.

Comment: This is an interesting problem. Is the answer $\dfrac{20!}{10!}$? I discarded the numbers 1-10. If the number is evenly divisible by multiples, then it is divisible by the number.

Comment: @mathguy80: The problem is just to find the least common multiple of $1, 2, \dots, 20$. Working it out, this is less than $\frac{20!}{10!}$.

Comment: I cleaned up @Andre's comment above, so the display problem should be fixed. So I also removed the discussion pertaining to *that*.

Comment: @Willie Wong: Thank you.  Is there anything that I could have done, beside better proofreading?

Comment: @Andre: here's a bit of a 'hack' that sometimes works for me http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/2652/comments-layout-break-if-math-expression-is-too-long/2818#2818

Comment: @AndréNicolas Actually, it's English rather than "school".  Even means, among other things, equal or fair; so an even division is one where every portion is the same and there is no remainder.

Comment: Anyone came because of #ProjectEuler100 ? :D

Comment: The first time I saw this expression, I thought that it meant the remainder is an even number...

Answer (score 31):

Evenly divisible means that you have no remainder. 
So, 20 is evenly divisible by 5 since 20 / 5 = 4.
Though, 21 is not evenly divisible by 5 since 21 / 5 = 4 R 1, or 4.2.

Answer (score 22):

evenly divisible = divisible .

Answer (score 3):

Evenly divisible is same as divisible. So, you are just looking for the L.C.M. of first $20$ natural numbers.

Answer (score 0):

"Evenly divisible" is equivalent to the term ``divides.''

For example, we can say that "20 is evenly divisible by 5", which is equivalent to saying that  "5 divides 20"; or in mathematical notation, $5 | 20$.

I am sure that the author of the question that you cite, "What is the smallest positive number that is evenly divisible by all of the numbers from 1 to 20?" chose to use the term "evenly divisible" instead of the more ordinary "divides", because to opt for the latter one would need to say something long-winded like, "1|n" and $2|n$ and \ldots and $20|n$, where $n$ is the smallest such integer in question.

Answer (score -3):

Evenly divisible would mean that the number is divisible by any number completely. To answer your question, the correct answer is 20! (20 factorial).

Comment: $20!$ is not the smallest such number. For example $19!$ already works, and that too is much bigger than needed.

Answer (score -4):

Means the same as "divisible". Answer is $2\times3\times5\times7\times11\times13\times17\times19$.

Comment: ... which is not divisible by $16$, for example.